# How to valid date format dd.MM.yyyy KENDO MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have problem with validation this date format in kedno UI: `dd.MM.yyyy`
For my culture (CS-CZ) kendo use this pattern: `d. M. yyyy`, but mostly used is format `dd.MM.yyyy`.

I tried everything but no success yet :/

My model:

```
public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

My kendo form:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
          .Name("ExpirationDate")
          .Culture("cs-CZ")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having? Is the issue that your getting a client side error message? (in which case you need configure the `$.validator`)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Javascript function to validate:

```
function IsValidDate(inputDate) {
    if (kendo.parseDate(inputDate) == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In View use this

```
@( Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
     .Name("FirstMODate")
     .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
     .ParseFormats(new string[] { "dd.MM.yyyy" })
     .Culture("cs-CZ")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px" })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DatePickerFor(model => model.ExpirationDate).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}");
```

Answer (score 0):

In web config, section system.web configure your culture

```
<globalization uiCulture="cs-CZ" culture="cs-CZ" />
```

In layout you need to include kendo culture javascript file

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.930/cultures/kendo.culture.cs-CZ.min.js")"></script>
```

and add javascript code

```
$(function () {
    kendo.culture("cs-CZ");
});
```

[Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview)

Or try to add custom rule for your date input:

```
kendo.ui.validator.rules.mvcdate = function (input) {
        if ($(input.attr('name')) === 'ExpirationDate') {
            return input.val() === "" || kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd.MM.yyyy") !== null;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I already do that... Kendo culture (cs-CZ) have this date format: d. M. yyyy I need to support dd.MM.yyyy  ... Like I wrote in my post